# Получение правильно текста с запроса к API телеграмм (Русские символы и значки)

Tags: c++, json, telegram-bot, unicode

Я посылаю запрос при помощи api телеграмма по типу [https://api.tlgr.org/botТутIdБота/getUpdates](https://api.tlgr.org/bot%D0%A2%D1%83%D1%82Id%D0%91%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/getUpdates) и получаю следующий ответ:

```
{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":258853250,
"message":{"message_id":383,"from":{"id":ТутId,"is_bot":false,"first_name":"Ник","username":"Ник","language_code":"ru"},"chat":{"id":Ник,"first_name":"Ник","username":"Ник","type":"private"},"date":1633388701,"text":"\ud83d\udcc3 \u041f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u0430"}}]}
```

Интересует конкретно `"text":"\ud83d\udcc3 \u041f\u0440\u0430\u0432\u0438\u043b\u0430"`

Моя libary для того чтобы работать с json не расшифровывает данный текст, увы.

Возможно у кого то завалялся код который решит данное недоразумение.
Выходной текст должен получиться следующим:  Правила

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130280/discussion-on-question-by-teeneerop-------api-).

Answer (score 0):

Похоже, этот текст закодирован в

- unicode escape
  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попробуйте использовать библиотеку для декодирования

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @pecenka, да, Unicode, но увы нигде не нашел решения данного вопроса для C++. Спасибо

Comment: @TeeNeeRop это банальные escape-последовательности: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C#Table_of_escape_sequences

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, требуется выполнить команду `url decode` перед отображением текста.

Пример: [топик на англ. SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154536/encode-decode-urls-in-c).