# Дешифровка Unicode Escape

Tags: c++, unicode, escape

Есть строка:
`std::string str = "\\ud83d\\udcc3 \\u041f\\u0440\\u0430\\u0432\\u0438\\u043b\\u0430"`

Нужно дешифровать любой Unicode Escapes ( НЕ ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ДАННОГО ТЕКСТА! )

Функция должна быть по типу:

```
std::string DecodeUnicodeEscapes(const std::string& strok) {
...Код который будет переставлять Escape's в нормальные символы
}
```

Comment: По вашей теме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28534221/c-convert-asii-escaped-unicode-string-into-utf8-string, там среди ответов была ссылка на функцию https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8

Comment: @gil9red не рабочий способ, проверял его. ( Тот который не буст. Бустом не пользуюсь )

Comment: Там из ответа нужен только первый пункт. Если тебе не нужен utf-8

Comment: @AlexeyTen Какой первый пункт? Убрать слеш?Если да, то это не то.

Comment: «parse 03a0 as hex, into a wchar_t» — в вашем случае может не в wchar_t, но по сути это и есть ответ

Comment: Взять адекватную C++ библиотеку дла работы с JSON. Qt или jsoncpp, например.

Comment: @gbg ну не может же быть, что нет готовой функции ...

Comment: Ну и кстати, раз у вас std::string, то что должно получиться на выходе для этой строки?

Comment: @AlexeyTen юникод текст по сути

Comment: «юникод текст по сути» — это какая-то абстрактная фраза показывающая что вы плохо понимаете чего же хотите. Байтики там какие должны быть?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Получение правильно текста с запроса к API телеграмм (Русские символы и значки)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1335205/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0-%d0%ba-api-%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc-%d0%a0%d1%83%d1%81%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%b8)

Comment: Дубликат, теперь выросший в [проблему X-Y](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/709/177993)

Comment: Опять же, если какой-то код лично у вас не работает, его надо выложить, чтобы люди, которые пытаются вам помочь, могли его запустить и проверить.